# Android Textview HTML not displaying colors?

Tags: android, html, textview, fromhtml

I am using like this it should show green color but showing black

all rgb values are dynamic(web service)
same code working in browser(W3 SCHOOLS)

```
mytextview.setText(Html
            .fromHtml("<font style=\"color: rgb(102, 204, 0);\">REGISTRATION</font>"));
```

Comment: mytextview.setText(Html .fromHtml("REGISTRATION")); shouldn't show green text...

Comment: why people are giving negative votes

Answer (score 1):

Where are you writing that "REGISTRATION" is green?

```
String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
String html = String.format("<font color='%s'>REGISTRATION</font>",hex);

mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
```

Comment: @SHASHIDHARMANCHUKONDA The colour you posted is the equivalent of #66CC00, use that instead of #00FF00

Comment: in my html i have rgb values

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String formattedText = "This is &lt;font color='#659D32'&gt;green&lt;/font&gt;";
textElement.setText(Html.fromHtml(formattedText));
```

Or another way is using `SpannableStringBuilder`

```
  String registration = "REGISTRATION";
  SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(registration);
  ForegroundColorSpan colorSpannable = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(102, 204, 0)); 
  spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(colorSpannable, 0, registration.length()-1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 
  mytextview.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<![CDATA[<font color='#659D32'>REGISTRATION</font>]]>"));
```

Or use SpannableStringBuilder:

```
String text = "REGISTRATION";
SpannableStringBuilder span = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#659D32")), 0,  text.length(), SpannableStringBuilder.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
mytextview.setText(span);
```